# How to check whether a string is a valid zsh glob pattern?

Tags: shell, validation, zsh, glob

I'm writing a zsh program that takes glob patterns as command-line arguments:

```bash
tss files --tags 'a*'  # lists files bearing a tag that starts with an 'a'
```

In order to validate input, is there a way to check whether a string is a syntactically valid glob pattern?

Ideally I would be able to validate both extended and non-extended patterns, leaving to the user the choice to use either, but I'd appreciate a solution that works with only one of the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to attempt to use the glob pattern with a `${~...}` expansion. This can be wrapped in a [try-block](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-try-blocks) to prevent the shell from exiting if there is an error:

```bash
checkGlob() {
  setopt nullglob
  { : ${~1} } always { TRY_BLOCK_ERROR=0 }
}

checkGlob 'aa*'; print $?
# => 0
checkGlob 'aa['; print $?
# => 1
```

Some of the pieces

- `setopt nullglob` - no error if there isn't a match for the glob pattern.
- `{ <try-block> } always { <always-block> }` - even if there's an error in the *try-block*, the code in the *always-block* will always be executed.
- `:` - no-op. The expansion that follows will be attempted, but no command will be executed.
- `${~1}` - expands the first positional parameter with `GLOB_SUBST` set, so glob patterns in the value will be processed.
- `TRY_BLOCK_ERROR=0` - resets the error status. Normally a runtime error like an incorrect glob pattern results in the shell exiting. This prevents that.
- The return code from the function is from the last command in the try-block, i.e. the `~` expansion.

---

The extended glob setting will determine which glob patterns are validated. This version of the function sets that option:

```bash
checkGlob() {
  setopt nullglob extendedglob localoptions
  pat=APREFIX${1:?}
  {
    : ${~pat} 
  } always {
    TRY_BLOCK_ERROR=0
  } &> /dev/null
}
```

This also has:

- `localoptions` - changes from `setopt` will only apply to this function.
- `pat=APREFIX...` - the `~` expansion is going to try to find actual files that match the pattern in the current directory - this is one way to make that list shorter. Another option is to change into an empty directory created with `mktemp`.
- `&> /dev/null` - block any output from the expansion.

You could run a similar check with extended glob turned off to try with both types, but note that many `zsh` utilities, such as `zmv`, simply turn extended globs on by default and call it a day.

Testing:

```bash
for gl in '*' 'a*' 'a[bc]' 'a[' 'a(.)' 'a(' 'a(#z)' '/tmp'; do
  if checkGlob $gl; then
      print "valid:   $gl"
  else
      print "invalid: $gl"
  fi
done

# => valid:   *
# => valid:   a*
# => valid:   a[bc]
# => invalid: a[
# => valid:   a(.)
# => invalid: a(
# => invalid: a(#z)
# => valid:   /tmp
```